# (Monaca)IOS9でのスクロール不備について

Tags: ios, monaca

いつもお世話になっております。
今回ご質問させていただきたいのは、IOS9での動作不具合についてです。

当方がmonacaで開発しているアプリケーションに関して、IOS8以前のものやandroidの機種に関しては問題なく作動いたしますが、IOS9またはIOS9が標準搭載されているiphone6だとスクロールがうまく起動しません。
（他の機能は問題ないようです。あくまでスクロールのみ）

これにはどのような原因・解決法が考えられますでしょうか？

また、先日Monacaから連絡のあったCordova 5.2にアップデートすれば、このような問題が解決するのでしょうか？　基本的な質問であれば大変恐縮ですがご回答の程何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: スクロールとは何のことを指しているのでしょうか？`ons-scroller`のことですか？それともブラウザ自体のスクロールの話でしょうか？ページ自体にだとしてもコンテンツにかかったスクロールなのかページに対するスクロールなのか分かりません。また、問題の実装コードを添付すると、より、解答がつきやすくなるかと思われます。現在では実装方法も分かりません。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。要領の得ない質問をしてしまい申し訳ありません。Onsenではなく通常のブラウザ自体のスクロールです。コンテンツのスクロール時に不備が発生します。